# How To Play Coup: The Resistance with more than one set of cards?

Tags: house-rules, expansions, coup

I recently purchased 2 sets of *Coup: The Resistance* So that I could play with more than 6 people. However, The included rules don't state how many of each card to use when dealing with more than 6 players.

I know the developers intended for more than 6 players to be able to play with additional cards but I can't find the recommended numbers anywhere.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Coup: Reformation](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgameexpansion/148931/coup-reformation) is the expansion for more than 6 players.

It contains 15 cards; 3 of each rather than 2 of each. I think the rules from the game say how many cards to use for how many players, since someone quotes it as 25(5 of each) cards for 9-10 players. Since you use 15(3 of each) cards for 6 players, I'm guessing you add 1 of each card for 7-8, 2 for 9-10 and 3 for 11-12.

The rules for reformation are slightly different, as it has 2 factions where you can take an action and 1 money to the almshouse to change your faction; 2 money to change someone else's faction; or take all the money from the almshouse if you do NOT have a Duke.

You are only allowed to attack people of the opposite faction to you, unless everyone is the same faction where you can attack whoever you want.

Comment: *What* contains 15 cards? The base game is 5x3=15.

Comment: The expansion also has 15 cards!

Comment: Good answer, however, the expansion has two of each of the original set and five of the new character, the Inquisitor. This means there are, with the original and expansion, five cards each of six card types. By your logic, there could only be up to ten with the true expansion, and twelve with two copies of the original, which is confirmed by the numbers listed on the boxes. Judging by the last game we played with 7 people and all the cards in, I like your numbers better and will start to use them. +1

Answer (score 1):

For every 1-2 players added to the game, you would add a full set of cards to the Court Deck.  This ensures that their is sufficient cards that nobody knows the full contents.  One thing that helped me was to purchase a packet of white label stickers.  I put one of these on the upper right hand corner of the face side of each card.  I wrote on the labels of 3 of the 5 of each card "2-6" and on 1 of the 5 I wrote "7-8" and on the last I wrote "9-10."  I also put them in sleeves to make them shuffle easier with the added sticker on them (as well as to protect the edges as mine were getting worn from play).  Now, when I pull the deck out, all I need to know is the number of players and I can quickly pull just the right number of cards by pulling all of the "2-6" cards and the additional sets based on player count without having to remember the card counts or look them up.

Comment: Does that information come from the designer or developer, or is it just an amount that you've found works well?

Comment: That information comes with the game.  My suggestion is adding the labels so you don't have to hunt that info down every time you set up.